# how to add tool tip to legends in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Is there any way we can add tool tip to legends in Highcharts ?

In example (https://jsfiddle.net/bdkxzf6t/) ,can we have tool tip defined when we do mouse over on Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Edge legends which are present in below pie chart ?

```
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Chrome',
        name2: 'Google Chrome',
        y: 61.41,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        name2: 'IE',
        y: 11.84
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        name2: 'FF',
        y: 10.85
    }, {
        name: 'Edge',
        name2: 'MSE',
        y: 4.67
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        name2: 'AS', 
        y: 4.18
    }, {
        name: 'Unknown',
        name2: 'NA',
        y: 7.05
    }]
}]
```

});

Thanks.

Comment: You can also try to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683867/adding-tooltip-to-legend-in-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

```js
//you need to add event in your code as shown below:
// you can change the tooltip position location if you'd like
// Build the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
   //------------------------     
      events: {
        load: function () {
          let chart = this,
              legend = chart.legend;
          for (let i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
            (function (i) {
              let item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;
              item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[i]]);
              }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                //chart.options.tooltip.enabled = false;
                chart.render();
              });
            })(i);
          }
        }
      }
        
//------------------------   
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}:HESAM <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name2}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
                        name2: 'Google Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            name2: 'IE',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            name2: 'FF',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            name2: 'MSE',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            name2: 'AS',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Unknown',
            name2: 'NA',
            y: 7.05
        }]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        This pie chart shows how the chart legend can be used to provide
        information about the individual slices.
    </p>
</figure>
```